# Discord bot does not send any messages out

Tags: java, discord

I have made discord bot integration in java.
But I'm getting an `indexoutofboundexception` and I'm not sure where to go from there.

```
WARN: Error executing task: MessageEvent [pendingQueue: 0 executionQueue: 5], 
[m java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at com.osroyale.util.Utility.randomElement(Utility.java:248) ~[bin/:?]
```

And the randomElement class

```
    public static <T> T randomElement(Collection<T> collection) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(collection).get((int) (RANDOM.nextDouble() * collection.size()));
}
```

Any ideas?

Edit: Added two classes related to the discord messages.

DiscordDispatcher class

```
 @EventSubscriber
    public void onMessageReceivedEvent(MessageReceivedEvent event) throws DiscordException, MissingPermissionsException {
        IMessage message = event.getMessage();
        long channel = event.getChannel().getLongID();
        String name = event.getAuthor().getName();
        String command = message.getContent();

        if (Discord.community == null && channel == Discord.COMMUNITY_CHANNEL) {
            Discord.community = event.getChannel();
        }

        if (command.equals("::players")) {
            Discord.communityMessage("There are currently " + World.getPlayerCount() + " players online!");
        } else if (command.equals("::staffonline")) {
            Discord.communityMessage("There are currently " + World.getStaffCount() + " staff online!");

        }
    }

}
```

And my Discord class

```
public class Discord {

    /** The community channel identification. */
    public static final long COMMUNITY_CHANNEL = 232389411260596224L;

    /** The client builder. */
    public static ClientBuilder builder;

    /** The discord client. */
    public static IDiscordClient client;

    /** The community channel instance. */
    static IChannel community;

    /** Handles starting the discord bot. */
    public static void start() {
        if (!Config.LIVE_SERVER) {
            return;
        }

        builder = new ClientBuilder().withToken(Config.DISCORD_TOKEN);
        client = builder.login();
        client.getDispatcher().registerListener(new DiscordDispatcher());
    }

    public static void communityMessage(String message) {
        if (community != null)
            community.sendMessage(message);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, your `List` is empty

Comment: This doesn't happen to anything else, in fact i'm also sending out game messages using the same logic, and I never have gotten error within this, so could you please enlighten me why it only happens when i'm trying to send out discord messages?

Comment: As I peer into your invisible code, I can say with confidence that I have absolutely no idea

Comment: I have updated code, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the library you use for discord, I'm using JDA so I'm giving you the solution, which is you have to add **`GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES`** when you create your bot and add the token it will be someone like that

**Example :**

```java
JDABuilder jda = JDABuilder.create(token, GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES);
```

hopefully, this is the case